# What is a word that indicates the layout of video feeds/sources on a video wall/screen - planogram?

Tags: synonyms, descriptive-grammar

Much like a [planogram](http://www.google.ca/imgres?imgurl=http://conceptdraw.com/How-To-Guide/picture/Planogram-of-magazines.png&imgrefurl=http://conceptdraw.com/How-To-Guide/planogram&h=630&w=1215&tbnid=L5CVKe0BGHFOyM:&docid=5kaZtmOIi7eWzM&ei=NsPpVffyFMGq-AHR9LTADw&tbm=isch&ved=0CEEQMygQMBBqFQoTCPflz_fi3ccCFUEVPgodUToN-A) indicates where the placements of retail products should be:

```
    plan·o·gram
    ˈplanəˌɡram/
    noun
    a diagram or model that indicates the placement of retail 
products on shelves in order to maximize sales.
```

The link above shows a diagram of clothing arrangements on a wall.  Instead of products, think video feed sources.

Could the same word be used to indicate the placement of video feeds on a video wall?

For example, security desk video screens are divided up into however many video feeds exist, and can be resized, or placed in a customized arrangement.

Planogram as well?

Comment: Are you talking about the arrangement itself or do you mean the model or plan of the arrangement?

Comment: Hi, I am referring to the plan of the arrangement.  The arrangement can be modified to suit whatever the user likes.  Updated question as well.

Comment: In my opinion there is nothing to stop you adopting the term. It seems reasonable. However the word isn't very well-known, at least outside of retail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need something more specific, and you're also probably aware of the term, but I'm not sure any other term would accurately describe what you're referencing.

I would go for juxtaposition, saying "the way the video sources are juxtaposed" a good option to me.

This term is used frequently in art critiques to describe how objects are placed within a photograph, but the technical definition of juxtaposition is:

1. an act or instance of placing close together or side by side, especially for comparison or contrast.
2. the state of being close together or side by side